# Hough transformation makes no sense

Tags: hough-transform

I have been very confused about this, so the basic idea of Hough's line discovery is that any line can be represented by a unique r and θ.
r = x.cos(θ) + y.sin(θ)

And further, every pixel on a given line will transform to the ***exact*** same r and θ for that line

but this assumption fails for the simplest of lines.

[image: plot]

In the given plot, two points are on the same line, but their **r** is different

explanation??

Comment: As the answer said, these are not polar coordinates. In your example it would be r = 0 and \theta = -sqrt(2)/2

Answer (score 0):

It is tempting to say that for the points (1, 1) and (3, 3), θ is π / 4 and r is the square root of 2 and 3 respectively.

These would be the polar coordinates of the points. But you can't expect two distinct points to have the same r and θ... How would you draw them?

r and θ are **not** the polar coordinates of the points here.
r is the distance from the origin to the line and θ is an angle such that the vector (cos θ, sin θ) is orthogonal to the line.
(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform for a figure my reputation does not allow me to post here).

With r and θ fixed in this way, all the points M=(x, y) on the line verify the equation: r = x.cos(θ) + y.sin(θ).
The right side can be seen as the dot product between the vector OM (where O is the origin) and the vector (cos θ, sin θ).

In your example, r would be 0 and θ would be 3π / 4.

For lines that do not go through the origin, (r, θ) are the polar coordinates of **one** point only on the line, which is the point closest to the origin.

Hope this helps.